# What's the general term of the squence $(U_n)_n$ such that $U_n+\frac{1}{U_{n-1}}=2$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

$$
U_n+\frac{1}{U_{n-1}}=2
$$
How we can find the general term of this sequence?

Comment: Trying *something*, for a start, usually help. What have you done (and where are you stuck)?

Comment: (also, you may want to specify, along with what you have tried, the initial condition of your sequence: what is $U_0$?)

Comment: sorry, the intial condition U_{0}=1, i multiply the two sides by n and tried to convert into another sequence whith i can calculate but I didnt succeed

Comment: $U_0 = 1$?! Have you tried to plug that in to see that $U_1= 2-\frac{1}{1}=1$, that $U_2= 2-\frac{1}{1}=1$, and so on? This is a constant sequence...

Answer (score 3):

After you have properly specified the initial condition $U_0$ (for instance, one cannot have $U_0=0$; and $U_0 = 1$ is trivial), a simple approach is **looking at a few terms and seeing what happens.**

$$\begin{align}
U_1 &= 2-\frac{1}{U_0} \\
U_2 &= 2-\frac{1}{U_1} = 2-\frac{1}{2-\frac{1}{U_0}}=\frac{3-\frac{2}{U_0}}{2-\frac{1}{U_0}} \\
U_3 &= 2-\frac{1}{U_2} = 2-\frac{2-\frac{1}{U_0}}{3-\frac{2}{U_0}}=\frac{4-\frac{3}{U_0}}{3-\frac{2}{U_0}}
\end{align}
$$
etc.

This will give you an idea of what to prove. Namely, one *could* guess that the general form is 
$$
 U_n = \frac{n+1-\frac{n}{U_0}}{n-\frac{n-1}{U_0}}
$$
and then proceed to prove it by induction.